# Adding Multiple PictureBoxes To Array

Tags: vb.net

So I have a total of 55 `PictureBox`es that I am trying to add to an array. The naming of them looks like the Following:

`Row1_Brick1`, `Row1_Brick2`, up to `Row1_Brick10`

There is a total of 10 rows and there is 1 less brick in each row.

This is what I have thought of so far to make this work:

```
Dim bricks(0 To 54) As PictureBox 'Total of 55 Bricks Spread Out

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Start of Loading 55 Bricks into the bricks() Array
    For i = 0 To 54
        For a = 1 To 10
            For am = 10 To 1 Step -1
                 bricks(i) = ("Row" & a & "_Brick" & am)
            Next
        Next 
    Next 
End Sub
```

Any ideas on how to do this would be great.

Comment: `For am = 10 To 1` probably should be `For am = 10 To 1 Step -1`, or else it won't actually count backwards.

Comment: Do you have other pictureboxes on that form with different names or all your pictureboxes should be stored in the array?

Comment: There is only 1 PictureBox named Paddle that cannot be added to the array. All of the other PictureBox's use the naming setup above.

Comment: _Me.Controls.OfType(PictureBox)().Where(Function(x) Not x.Name.StartsWith("Row").ToArray()_

Comment: @Steve Shouldn't that be ...`OfType(Of PictureBox)`...

Comment: I don't think I see a question. Are there errors?

Comment: @LarsTech It gives me an error where the "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'

Comment: `bricks(i) = CType(Me.Controls("Row" & a & "_Brick" & am), PictureBox)`

Comment: You are also going to have to fix your loops, as you have them now, it will eventually be looking for the 10th control on the 10th row, which doesn't exist.  Plus it will be overwriting every element of the array so that they all contain a reference to the *last* `PictureBox`.

Comment: Is `CType()` really necessary? At least `DirectCast()` would be a better choice (fewer runtime type checks, since we as the programmer know we _already have_ a PictureBox), but I wonder if even that much is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a jagged array, which would look like this (note that this is 0-indexed rather than 1-indexed, as with your control names):

```
 Dim bricks(10)() As PictureBox

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Set up child arrays
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
         bricks(i) = New PictureBox(9-i)
         'Set up each element in the array
         For j As Integer = 0 To 9 - i 
             bricks(i)(j) = Me.Controls("Row" & i + 1 & "_Brick" & j + 1)
         Next j
    Next 
End Sub
```

But if you really only want a single array, it is at least easier to set up (you might be able to get it down to a single line):

```
Dim bricks() As PictureBox

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bricks = Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)().ToArray()
End Sub
```

If you need to, you can put in a `Where()` call to limit to pictureboxes where the name matches your patter, though it would be better to put these controls into a common Panel or GroupBox you can use as the parent rather than the form. You can also use an `Orderby()` call to make sure the PictureBoxes are returned in the proper sequence:

```
Dim bricks() As PictureBox

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bricks = BrickPanel.Controls.
                OfType(Of PictureBox)().
                OrderBy(Function(pb) pb.Name). 'Naive OrderBy... 10 is before 2. I leave it to the OP to fix that part
                ToArray()
End Sub
```

If you are unconformtalbe with the Linq functions, the trick is to increment your result array index as part of your inner loop, rather than having a separate loop by itself:

```
 Dim bricks(54) As PictureBox

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For r As Integer = 1 To 10
         For c As Integer = 1 to 11 - r
             bricks(i) = Me.Controls("Row" & r & "_Brick" & c)
             i+=1
         Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is completely untested, because I was too lazy to create a new project and set up a form the same way you have, but it should be *close*.

```
Dim arr(54) As PictureBox
Dim index As Integer = 0
For row As Integer = 1 To 10
    For col As Integer = 1 To 10 - row + 1 'Max column is based on the inverted value of the current row
        arr(index) = Ctype(f.Controls("Row" & row & "_Brick" & col), PictureBox)
        index += 1
    Next
Next
```

This method of getting the control by the name explicitly will avoid any errors due to the order that the controls were added to the form.

Comment: Maybe increment index _after_ assigning to arr in the loop. Otherwise position 0 is empty and you'll end up assigning to position 55.